# Isomorphism between multiplicative modulo groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Group G = {1,2,3,4,5,6} multiplicative modulo 7
Group H = {1,5,7,11,13,17} multiplicative modulo 18

Show the groups are cyclic.

Found a generator 3 of G and 5 of H. How can I check quickly they are generators without computing all powers.

Provide a isomorphic between the groups

Identity goes to identity is obvious what about the rest? I was thinking 3 goes to 5 using (i)?

Comment: No clearly isn't

Comment: Yes, it clearly is: $U(7)$, the first group is cyclic by the duplicate. The second is $U(18)$, which is also  cyclic with six elements by the duplicate, hence must be isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

The isomorphism between two cyclic groups can be obtained by mapping the generator of the first cyclic group to the generator of the second cyclic group.  In your case, define a map that takes element 3 to element 5, and since the map must be a homomorphism, it must take element $3^i$ to element $5^i$.